# YQL Queries with OAuth Gives Unauthorized

Tags: c#, oauth, yql

I have been trying YQL with private queries.

I'm using sample code by yahoo developer network.
https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/codeexamples.html#oauth_csharp

Code looks like below.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string consumerKey = "dj0yJmk9SzhxdHFrY0pHOTZ1JmQ9WVdrOWRVTTBOM1JhTkRRbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD01Ng--";
        string consumerSecret = "34fd168eb4a91cd4c5cb2f9ec60e4ed74b278f00";
        var uri = new Uri("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys");
        string url, param;
        var oAuth = new OAuthBase();
        var nonce = oAuth.GenerateNonce();
        var timeStamp = oAuth.GenerateTimeStamp();
        var signature = oAuth.GenerateSignature(uri, consumerKey,
        consumerSecret, string.Empty, string.Empty, "GET", timeStamp, nonce,
        OAuthBase.SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1, out url, out param);

        using (WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}?{1}&oauth_signature={2}",
        url, param, signature)).GetResponse()) { }
    }
}
```

its Getting complied, but when I execute it gives me runtime exception.

> *The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.*

Comment: Anyone who is reading this..through lot of research I found out there are two types of OAuth . 2 Legged and 3 legged , this one above is 2 legged which indirectly means it will not present user with Login page in this case yahoo login, so it can not fetch data which is Private/ Related to user.

Comment: So how did you solve this? I am trying to do the same to get symbols but getting this same exception. It works fine when I use public url. Is this what you did?